# Unexpected asynchronous action in "mounted" axios in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

As a newbie to Vue.js, I have a component which needs to get profile data from remote server:

```
<template>

 <div v-if="token">
      {{profile}}
  </div>
 
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Profile',

  data () {
    return {
          profile: {},
    }

  },

  computed: {
    token () {
      return this.$store.getters.getToken; 
    },

    mounted () {
        return axios
        .get( this.BASE_URL + '/profile')
        .then( res => {
                    this.profile = res.data;
                    console.log('profile is:', res.data);

          })            
    },

  },

}
</script>
```

I followed [Using Axios to Consume APIs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) from the official cookbook but get these errors:

```
error: Unexpected asynchronous action in "mounted"  

  84 |     mounted () {
> 85 |         return axios
     |                ^
```

And also

```
error: Unexpected side effect in "mounted" computed property  
  86 |         .get( this.BASE_URL + '/profile')
  87 |         .then( res => {
> 88 |                     this.profile = res.data;
     |                     ^
```

If I omiit `return` from mounted, I get also this error:

```
error: Expected to return a value in "mounted" computed property
```

Got really perplexed. Appreciate your hints to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mounted should be the same level as computed

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Profile',

  data() {
    return {
      profile: {},
    };
  },
  computed: {
    token() {
      return this.$store.getters.getToken;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/profile').then(res => {
      this.profile = res.data;
      console.log('profile is:', res.data);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```